# Why my bootstrap css class wont apply on <a> like it works on <button>?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am working on setting up my social icons on footer using font awesome and bootstrap-social.css. When i do this

```
<button class="btn btn-social-icon btn-facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></button>
```

it works properly [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuXhY.png)

but when i try to use same css classes in < a > tag

```
<a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
```

i get result like this [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ke1ni.png),its hover,icon in the middle, etc. styles are messed up.

There is a 'how to use' example on original page where i dl-ed bootstrap-social.css with < a > tag used because of that i am confused.
So my goal is to apply that button like style to a link or add link in button with that style if its possible somehow. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to assign a white text color to the `i` element within your `a.btn`

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-facebook" href="here paste your link"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
```

When you use `<a>` element it has default hover properties,so you can disable them.
Here is example: https://jsbin.com/qogunenura/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: after your help i managed to preserve button style using !important but hover is still broken ,can u tell me where i can find that <a> default hover properties ?

Comment: it's probably because of libraries you use
Try write css with selector,using !important is very bad idea.I cant tell you where is default hover properties in your case,without link on your website.
Anyway try this variant:
https://jsbin.com/rizuwaxuce/edit?html,css,output 

Your problem is here from string number 40 till 45:
https://github.com/lipis/bootstrap-social/blob/gh-pages/bootstrap-social.css

Comment: still cant figure it out ,i published website with only index page here http://bearaart.somee.com/Home/